# Call Controller Function from Directive (with params passed from directive)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive

So what I want to achieve is to pass a function (that takes in 2 parameters) and is defined in the controller, into the directive and gets called with params from the directive with directive params.

```
.on('click', function(d, i){
    // here I want to call the function from the controller,
    ctrlCB(d, i);
})
```

My controller looks a bit like this:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('d3')
    .directive('verticalBarChart', verticalBarChart);
    verticalBarChart.$inject = ['d3Service', '$window', '$parse'];
    function verticalBarChart(d3Service, $window, $parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                data: '=',
                click: '=click'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                d3Service.d3()
                .then(function (d3) {
                    // some more d3.js stuff
                    svg.selectAll('rect')
                        .data(data).enter()
                        .append('rect')
                        .attr('width', barWidth)
                        .on('click', function (d, i) {
                            scope.click(d, i); // THIS IS THE ONE I'M INTERESTED IN !
                            // on click it calls the function, but the params don't get passed in
                        })
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

the Directive:

```
<div vertical-bar-chart bar-padding="2" data="barData" click="clickCallback"></div>
```

and in the controller I would for example have a

```
$scope.clickCallback = function(d, i){
    $location.url('/item/'+i)
}
```

Comment: Can you create your current solution on plunkr or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st thing I'd like to correct is, you should be using `&`(expression binding) instead of using `=`(two way binding) when you wanted to pass `function` to directive and call it from there.

```
scope: {
   data: '=',
   click: '&click',
   //or just kept it like below where `click` alias is redudant
   //click: '&'
},
```

Then do call method on `click` attribute rather than just having its reference there.

```
click="clickCallback(d, i)"
```

For calling method from directive, pass its parameter values in `JSON` format & run digest cycle to update its binding as we are modifying scope from external events.

```
scope.click({d: d, i: i});
scope.$apply();
```

Comment: @Michael glad to know that.. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

update: Pankaj Parkar has the better answer but I'll leave my post as a poor alternative instead of deleting it.

I don't have access to your service that draws your bar chart, but I'll share how I would have a child directive talk to a parent controller and hopefully answer your question by simplifying the click to a div bar representing your end chart.

```
   $scope.init = function(){

       var onBarClickHandler = function(ev){
           d3.event.stopPropagation();
           $scope.click( $scope.data );
       }

       var bar = d3.select("#bar");
       bar.on("click", onBarClickHandler );
    }
```

[codepen: angular d3 directive parent controller talk](http://codepen.io/headwinds/pen/zqZZKX/)

Personally, when writing angular1 code, I like to move logic into the controller instead of placing it in the link directive but this should also work if you prefer having it in the link.